# KafkaMessageListenerContainer.stop() is not stopping consumption of messages in message listener

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

UseCase: Given topic with 100 messages in kafka topic, I want to read messaged from offset 10 to offset 20. I could able to fetch from beginning offset. when i reach end offset, I have written code to stop the container.Even after execution of code, Consumer can consume further messages(from offset 21).**It only stops after reading all messages in the topic**

```
@Service
public class Consumer1  implements MessageListener<String, GenericRecord> {

 @Override
  public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> data) {
    log.info("feed record {}", data);
    if (data.offset() == 20) {
      feedService.stopConsumer();
    }
  }
}

@Service
public class FeedService{

    // start logic here

   public void stopConsumer() {
    kafkaMessageListenerContainer.stop();
  }

}
```

Note: I am using spring-kafka latest version(2.6.4). One observation is container stop method is being executed but consumer is not getting closed.And no errors on output

Answer (score 1):

The `stop()` doesn't terminate the current records batch cycle:

```
while (isRunning()) {
            try {
                pollAndInvoke();
            }
            catch (@SuppressWarnings(UNUSED) WakeupException e) {
                // Ignore, we're stopping or applying immediate foreign acks
            }
```

That `pollAndInvoke()` calls a `KafkaConsumer.poll()`, gets some records collection and invokes your `onMessage()` on each record. At some point you decide to call the stop, but it doesn't mean that we are really in the end of that records list to exit immediately.

We really stop on the next cycle when that `isRunning()` returns `false` for us already.

Comment: Would consumer be terminated at the last message in the topic ? or it will be terminated after fetching few records(in the batch) after calling stop() at certain offset?

Comment: Right now it is terminated when the whole records iterator is processed. As I said: you stop in the middle of the batch, but we don't check for that state until the next polling cycle. It doesn't mean that last processed message is really the last one in the topic. You probably can think about controlling how many records you fetch looking to the particular Kafka consumer options.

Comment: We should probably add a configuration option to stop immediately (after the current record is processed). Please open a GitHub issue.

Comment: @ArtemBilan can we configure max.poll.records consumer property. so that we don't need to process all records in the topic, but remaining records in the batch (configured number of records )would be processed and consumer would be stopped

Comment: @GaryRussell I had opened git hub issue ,but that has been closed.Should i recreate one more?

Comment: Gary has reopened your issue. Yes `max.poll.records` is the way to go for you. But again: if you configure it as a `10` and you have only 8 and you'd like to stop after 5th, the rest 3 will be processed, too. In your terms everything in the topic is going to be processed. Just because all the records fit to a single poll request.

Comment: Regardless of this behavior, you should not call `stop()` on the listener thread - it will cause a delay (because `stop()` waits for the listener thread to exit until `shutdownTimeout`). Call `stop(() -> { })` instead.